# Split fix value to countries based on pre-defined share per country

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e0d522953ab54785d95b8dd16abc751)**

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    channel VARCHAR,
    costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(event_date, country, channel, costs)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_03', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_01', '400'),

('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_02', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_03', '300');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date    |    country   |            costs            |
--------------|--------------|-----------------------------|---------
2020-02-08    |      DE      |        240  (=400 x 0.6)    |    
2020-02-08    |      FR      |        120  (=400 x 0.3)    |   
2020-02-08    |      NL      |         40  (=400 x 0.1)    |   
--------------|--------------|-----------------------------|---------
2020-04-15    |      DE      |        180  (=300 x 0.6)    |   
2020-04-15    |      FR      |         90  (=300 x 0.3)    |   
2020-04-15    |      NL      |         30  (=300 x 0.1)    |
```

---

I want to split the `costs` based on **pre-defined shares** to **each country per day**. 
The shares are: `DE = 0.6, FR = 0.3, NL = 0.1`

```
SELECT
c.event_date,
c.country,
c.costs
FROM costs c
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Do you have an idea what query I need to achieve this?

Comment: Put the shares in another table, join them, and use the values to make the calculation

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT c.event_date,
       c.country,
       (CASE WHEN c.country = 'DE' THEN 0.6 * c.costs
             WHEN c.country = 'FR' THEN 0.3 * c.costs
             WHEN c.country = 'NL' THEN 0.1 * c.costs
        END) as allocated_costs
FROM costs c
GROUP BY c.event_date, c.country, c.costs
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

You can more conveniently store the values in a derived table, if you prefer:

```
SELECT c.event_date, c.country, (v.alloc * c.costs) as allocated_costs
FROM costs c JOIN
     (VALUES ('DE', 0.6), ('FR', 0.3), ('NL', 0.1)
     ) v(country, alloc)
     USING (country)
GROUP BY c.event_date, c.country, c.costs, v.alloc
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=103758b58608d945de463d559df6375c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Just for my documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3531aea5ec74680545fe342903874168

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be to add those rates into a table and use that table in your query.

to illustrate how you can do it with hard-coded values in your query:

```
SELECT
c.event_date,
c.country,
c.costs * case country when  'DE' then 0.6 
          when 'FR' then 0.3
          when 'NL' then 0.1 
          end 
FROM costs c
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2;
```