# Divided fix value based on pre-defined share to countries but euqally to channels

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=99b053e1082bff3a7ab7ef0f01c35215)**

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    channel VARCHAR,
    costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(event_date, country, channel, costs)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_02', '400'),

('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_02', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_02', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_02', '300');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date    |    country   |     channel       |            costs              |
--------------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|---------
2020-02-08    |      DE      |     channel_01    |      120  (=400 x 0.6 / 2)    | 
2020-02-08    |      DE      |     channel_02    |      120  (=400 x 0.6 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      FR      |     channel_01    |       60  (=400 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      FR      |     channel_02    |       60  (=400 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      NL      |     channel_01    |       20  (=400 x 0.1 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      NL      |     channel_02    |       20  (=400 x 0.1 / 2)    |  
--------------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|---------
2020-04-15    |      DE      |     channel_01    |       90  (=300 x 0.6 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      DE      |     channel_02    |       90  (=300 x 0.6 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      FR      |     channel_01    |       45  (=300 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      FR      |     channel_02    |       45  (=300 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      NL      |     channel_01    |       15  (=300 x 0.1 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      NL      |     channel_02    |       15  (=300 x 0.1 / 2)    |
```

---

With the below query from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401848/split-fix-value-to-countries-based-on-pre-defined-share-per-country) I am able to divide the costs based on pre-defined shares `(DE=0.6, FR=0.3, NL=0.1)` to each country per day.

```
SELECT
c.event_date,
c.country,
c.channel,
(CASE WHEN c.country IN('DE') THEN c.costs * 0.6 
      WHEN c.country IN('FR') THEN c.costs * 0.3
      WHEN c.country IN('NL') THEN c.costs * 0.1 END) AS costs
FROM costs c
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

However, as you can see in the expected result I also want to divide the **cost per country** **equally** to each channel.

How do I need to modify the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use window functions:

```
SELECT 
c.event_date, 
c.country, 
c.channel,
c.costs,

  (CASE WHEN c.country IN ('DE') THEN c.costs * 0.6 
        WHEN c.country IN ('FR') THEN c.costs * 0.3
        WHEN c.country IN ('NL') THEN c.costs * 0.1
  END) * (1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.event_date, c.country)) AS costs_allocated
  
FROM costs c
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=178cdd30413ee9cfa3c9f23bf84127e6)**